# Headers are repeated from first line in python table

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, physics, tabulate

I dont understand why the headers of my table are repeated on every row rather than just the first row as expected.

Also why my `print("Closest Approach", min(table))` is also repeated onto every row rather than just singularly printing the minimum value of the distances within the table on separate output. Could someone advise on where I have went wrong or how it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried the `headers="firstrow"` and `headers="keys"` functions but to no avail.

My link for the code is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kUSSu4ujIzj9fQ2Vl-KL2KMSVTde7DdR#scrollTo=lCRtZWPw-eAI),if you can identify problem from output.

Here is the Google Colab code for reference;

```
def update(i):
    exdata.append(xelist[i])
    eydata.append(yelist[i])
    
    jxdata.append(xjlist[i])
    jydata.append(yjlist[i])
    
    line_e.set_data(exdata,eydata)
    point_e.set_data(xelist[i],yelist[i])
    text_e.set_position((xelist[i],yelist[i]))
    
    line_j.set_data(jxdata,jydata)
    point_j.set_data(xjlist[i],yjlist[i])
    text_j.set_position((xjlist[i],yjlist[i]))
    
    point_s.set_data(xslist[i],yslist[i])
    text_s.set_position((xslist[i],yslist[i]))
    
    ax.set_xlim(-5.8*AU,5.8*AU)
    ax.set_ylim(-5.8*AU,5.8*AU)
    
    dist = sqrt((exdata[-1] - jxdata[-1])**2 + (eydata[-1] - jydata[-1])**2)
    annotation.set_data(x=exdata[-1], y=eydata[-1], dx=jxdata[-1] - exdata[-1], dy=jydata[-1] - eydata[-1])
    text_a.set_position(((exdata[-1] + jxdata[-1]) / 2, (eydata[-1] + jydata[-1]) / 2))
    text_a.set_text(f"{dist/1e9:.1f} km(Mill) ") 
    table = [[(i),(f"{dist/1e9:.1f}")]]

    print("Closest Approach", min(f"{dist/1e9:.1f}"))

    print(tabulate(table, headers=["Time since last Closest Approach (Days)","Distance Between Planets (km*Mill) "]))
```

Comment: use triple ``` for opening and closing a block of code and start at a new line

Comment: Hi @cards, thank you for that tip, I was confused as to how to  correctly upload code to the question. Have you any advice relating to my initial problem. I would appreciate any help at all. Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have all the dependencies that the program requires. Notice that at each frame of the animation you are creating a new `tabulate` object. Maybe defined a global list (outside `update`), smt like `tables = [table_i0, table_i1, ...]` which is updated inside `update`, and outside create the `tabulate(tables, headers=...)`?